# Ajax answer shows a part of the code not the message

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax call, and I substring the answer.

Here a part of the code:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: "index.php?module=mobiloldal&action=m_foglalas_function",
    data: {call: "m_detailsChange", menu: "never", q: str, lang: lan },
    async: false,
    success: function(msg)
    {
     var text=msg.substring(msg.indexOf("start")+7,msg.indexOf("end"));
    jQuery("#" + info).html(text);
    }
});
```

on some device(usually iPhone) the result contains only this part of the code:`")+7,msg.indexOf("end"));`

[image: 1]

What do you think, what is the problem?
Thanks for the answers in advance.

Comment: Most likely: The URL doesn't return what you think it returns.

Comment: use `alert(msg)` to see what is value of it. I think it will be the source code of page it self.

Comment: I agree, it looks like the msg you are getting is that line of code so when you extract from start to end you get everything in between. Try using `console.log(msg)` to see exactly what you are getting back.